# Installing Arch Linux Error: grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory

Tags: arch-linux, grub

I'm trying to install Arch Linux on my machine, following [these](https://youtu.be/HpskN_jKyhc) instructions.

```
timedatectl set-ntp true
timedatectl status
cfdisk
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda2
mkswap /dev/sda3
swapon /dev/sda3
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
pacstrap /mnt base linux linux-firmware
genfstab -U /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab
arch-chroot /mnt
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/myRegion/myCity /etc/localtime
hwclock --systohc
locale-gen

nano/etc/locale.conf
LANG=en_US.UTF-8

nano /etc/hostname
myhostname

nano /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1       localhost
127.0.1.1 myhostname.localdomain myhostname

passwd
useradd -m newusername
passwd newusername
usermod -aG wheel,audio,video,optical,storage newusername
pacman -S vim
visudo
pacman -S grub
grub-install /dev/sda
```

At `cfdisk`, I configured my partitions as follows:

```
sda1: EFI system partition
sda2: Linux x86-64 root
sda3: Linux swap
```

At the mounting steps, I did the following:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1
mkswap /dev/sda3
swapon /dev/sda3
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

The rest is mostly the same, just with my own info.

I'm currently stuck here:

```
/# grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory
```

I've checked out a few similar post with this problem but it hasn't helped me progress.

How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You missed the EFI partitioning part, I am assuming you want to use `/dev/sda1` as your EFI partition.

```bsh
mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sda1
```

after `mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`
you should

```bsh
mkdir -p /mnt/boot/EFI
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/EFI
```

this should work. For more detail please go through the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFI_system_partition#Format_the_partition)